# Insert does not work on model with composite id in loopback

Tags: loopbackjs

I have a table named Xml_Mapping with composit ID on MYSQL.
When i try to insert into table; in runtime or from StrongLoop API Explorer, i could not insert.

When i debug, i see wrong insert sql :

```
    INSERT INTO `Xml_Mapping`(`SiteId`,`SystemKeyId`,`TargetKey`) VALUES(1,1,'stockcode') 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
```

as you can see, "UPDATE" sql was not completed. So it could not be executed...

How can i solve this problem?

Xml_Mapping Table:

```
    SiteId INT NOT NULL,
    SystemKeyId INT NOT NULL,
    TargetKey VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (SiteId, SystemKeyId, TargetKey),
    CONSTRAINT XML_MAPPING_fk1 FOREIGN KEY (SiteId) REFERENCES site (Id),
    INDEX XML_MAPPING_fk1 (SiteId)
```

Xml-mapping.json :

```
{
  "name": "XmlMapping",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": false,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "mysql": {
    "schema": "uygunca",
    "table": "Xml_Mapping"
  },
  "properties": {
    "SiteId": {
      "type": "Number",
      "id": 1,
      "required": true,
      "length": null,
      "precision": 10,
      "scale": 0,
      "mysql": {
        "columnName": "SiteId",
        "dataType": "int",
        "dataLength": null,
        "dataPrecision": 10,
        "dataScale": 0,
        "nullable": "N"
      },
      "_selectable": false
    },
    "SystemKeyId": {
      "type": "Number",
      "id": 2,
      "required": true,
      "length": null,
      "precision": 10,
      "scale": 0,
      "mysql": {
        "columnName": "SystemKeyId",
        "dataType": "int",
        "dataLength": null,
        "dataPrecision": 10,
        "dataScale": 0,
        "nullable": "N"
      },
      "_selectable": false
    },
    "TargetKey": {
      "type": "String",
      "id": 3,
      "required": true,
      "length": 100,
      "precision": null,
      "scale": null,
      "mysql": {
        "columnName": "TargetKey",
        "dataType": "varchar",
        "dataLength": 100,
        "dataPrecision": null,
        "dataScale": null,
        "nullable": "N"
      },
      "_selectable": false
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": []
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alter your table **Xml_Mapping** and set **autoincrement** for field **SiteId**
and you don't need to provide **SiteId** in JSON

Run

```
ALTER TABLE `Xml_Mapping`
MODIFY `SiteId` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Change your model **Xml-mapping.json :** and set properties for **SiteId** ***"required": false,*** 
It should be like

```
{
  "name": "XmlMapping",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": false,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "mysql": {
    "schema": "uygunca",
    "table": "Xml_Mapping"
  },
  "properties": {
    "SiteId": {
      "type": "Number",
      "id": 1,
      "required": false,
      "length": null,
      "precision": 10,
      "scale": 0,
      "mysql": {
        "columnName": "SiteId",
        "dataType": "int",
        "dataLength": null,
        "dataPrecision": 10,
        "dataScale": 0,
        "nullable": "N"
      },
      "_selectable": false
    },
    "SystemKeyId": {
      "type": "Number",
      "id": 2,
      "required": true,
      "length": null,
      "precision": 10,
      "scale": 0,
      "mysql": {
        "columnName": "SystemKeyId",
        "dataType": "int",
        "dataLength": null,
        "dataPrecision": 10,
        "dataScale": 0,
        "nullable": "N"
      },
      "_selectable": false
    },
    "TargetKey": {
      "type": "String",
      "id": 3,
      "required": true,
      "length": 100,
      "precision": null,
      "scale": null,
      "mysql": {
        "columnName": "TargetKey",
        "dataType": "varchar",
        "dataLength": 100,
        "dataPrecision": null,
        "dataScale": null,
        "nullable": "N"
      },
      "_selectable": false
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": []
}
```

and then use your JSON as

```
{
  "SystemKeyId": 1,
  "TargetKey": 'stockcode'  
}
```